# How to sent emails (bulk) simultaneously

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, email

I make a client application with vb.net, and i want to send emails to many recipients simultaneously. I know how to send one email, but i don't know how to send many of them. What i should to do, create many smtpclient objects or send them with a thread?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to send one email to many people, separate the list of people to send to with semicolons. Eg:

```
Send("me@me.com", "you@you.com; someone@else.com; h@i.com", "Hi!", "Hi there guys!")
```

Also, what is the importance of sending all of the emails at the exact same time? Is it OK if they are sent a second after each other?

Comment: @user1005633 What is the importance of sending them all at the same time though? This method will send them around the same time.

Comment: basically, i want to send the message to each person, separately... For example, if i want to send the same mail to 50 people i want to send these messages parallel, in order to finish it (sending process) quickly...

Answer (score 1):

send them with using threading capability.
creating using many smtpclient objects takes many resourcec & this can be reason for low performance .
hence it is better to use threading facility with help of queue, take some job at a time from queue & process them

```
Dim t As New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf SendEmails))
t.Start(emailThread)
```

Comment: So, what should i have in the SendEmails method? i don't understand what you mean with "help of queue"..

Comment: queue is data structure in which you can store your jobs

Comment: Yes, i know what queue is, i don't understand what jobs the will the queue has.